# Swift - Segue Transition Left to Right without embedding Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, segue

This may be a simple one but Im trying to find an elegant solution to it. Is there a way to make the segue transition go left to right rather than the default bottom up other than by embedding a Navigation Controller? Ive used all the available storyboard segues and they dont make any noticeable change

Comment: Try setting a different `modalTransitionStyle` for your view controller - see the Apple Docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalTransitionStyle).

Comment: Thanks for that. I found that the best solution for me was to just embed a Navigation Controller but then hiding it by using the code: self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for that. I found that the best solution for me was to just embed a Navigation Controller but then hiding it by using the code:

**self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true**

Comment: How did this solve the question of transitioning from left to right?